# Issue with programmatically adding ActivityIndicator with WKWebView, not appearing

Tags: swift, xcode

My code successfully loads the web page that I want it to; however, I'm having issues adding my activity indicator for while it is loading.

I am relatively new to swift, so I was reading other stackexchange examples. I created a UIActivityIndicator, set it in the override func, but it doesn't show up.

The webpage loads fine. Here is the runnable code.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class FeedbackWebViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        indicator.center = webView.center
        indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        webView.addSubview(indicator)

        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

        self.indicator.startAnimating()
    }


    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        indicator.stopAnimating()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        indicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DONT override loadView. bad things may happen.
move code in didLoad. it should work.

Comment: I moved the 3 lines related to indicator into the didLoad, but it's still not appearing when a page is attempting to load

Comment: I also just added all the code into viewDidLoad but still I'm not seeing it. Am I missing something or have forgotten to initialize it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

try to put the related 3 lines to viewDidAppear rather than viewDidLoad. It works for me.